# How to start the sentence with "or" in Chinese?

Tags: word-choice, mandarin

I assume a sentence that starts with `or` in Mandarin, something like the follows:

> M: Where are you from?
>
> F: Chicago.
>
> M: No, I meant which city you are from in China?
>
> M: Or did you grew up in US?

In these sentences, is it correct to just use 或 to start the sentence? I haven't seen the kind of usage of 或; I only saw it is used within the sentence, combining multiple related items.

> M: 你是从哪里来的？
>
> F: 芝加哥
>
> M: 我的意思是你是从哪个中国城市来的？
>
> M: 或，你在美国出生和长大了吗？

Or if it is not correct, how should I start the sentence with `or`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the translation is fine, but if you speak it, that's pretty weird.

colloquially, we use `還是說` or `或是說` or `或者說`

So, the sentences are better to be spoken like this:

> M:你從哪來的?
>
> F:芝加哥
>
> M:我的意思是你是從中國的哪個城市來的?
>
> M:或者說,你是在美國土生土長的?

for the most part, we add few redundancies to sentence to make it fluent.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the same in Mandarin?

Comment: It's already Mandrain.